# shadow in material design

Tags: shadows, google-material-design

I attached a photo with this question,
in the photo there is a folder that have a small shadow I can't design a shadow like that in photoshop.
would you mind help me?
[excuse me for Mistakes in writing. I'm not English.]

[image: google drive app]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make a new layer
2. Drop it beneath the folder picture
3. Draw the shadow shape with the polygon lasso
4. Fill it with the shadow colour
5. Select a grunge effect eraser brush
6. Erase a section of the shadow
7. Done

You can use a thing called a layer mask instead of the eraser on step 5-6, that will enable you to go back if you're not happy. To apply a layer mask:

1. Select the shadow layer
2. Click the icon that looks like this [image: circled layer mask icon]
3. You'll see a square appear on the layer, this is the mask

   - You can only paint in black and white here, black will make parts of your layer invisible, just like erasing it. But if you're unhappy you can always go back over with white and it will reveal the layer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello and thanks for contributing. But please do not answer questions that do not meet our question requirements.

Comment: Apologies, do the questions themselves need to meet a certain standard to be considered for answering?

I signed up to this site a while ago and revisited it late last night, so may have glossed over some of the read first info.

Comment: No worries. You can find out more about what is on and off topic on our [help] page. Otherwise you can look at the flagging reasons for questions and on [meta]. This question in particular doesn't meet our requirement of including what they tried and why it didn't work with screenshots. It lacks the desired results are, what resources they referenced and why those didn't work - all according to [this meta post](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/699/23061)